# JQuery DataTables: position of the table

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm somewhat perplexed trying to move a table over to the left of the page. I've tried left-aligning the containing div, the wrapper div, and the table element, but when the DataTable initializes it is always centered on the page.

Is there a way to change the initialization settings or something? Or is there a CSS trick I'm overlooking?

The structure I have after initialization is like this:

```
<containing div>
<wrapper div class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
<table class="dataTable no-footer" role="grid">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add `text-align: right` to the container.

Comment: That worked! I don't quite understand how though - when I set text-align:left for the container, the table stayed centered.

Comment: You don't provide enough information for me to diagnose the reason; I just threw out the most likely possibility.